# How to render keys and values from JSON into a grid

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid

I have a large JSON file (sample below) that I am trying to arrange into a well formatted grid. This is what I have right now:

```js
const txt = '[{"prompts": "Breakfast","text": "The breakfast table is a microcosm of the wider world. How do we understand the people around us"},{"prompts": "Water Balloons","text": "This studio looks at the concept of water-balloons or rubber balloons"}]'


const obj = JSON.parse(txt);
let text = "";
for (let i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
  text = obj[i].prompts;
  names = obj[i].text;

}
  let prompt = document.createElement("div");
prompt.setAttribute("class", "box");
prompt.innerHTML = text;
document.getElementsByClassName("wrapper")[0].appendChild(prompt);

let output = document.createElement("div");
output.setAttribute("class", "box");
output.innerHTML = names;
document.getElementsByClassName("wrapper")[0].appendChild(output);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 40px;
}

.box {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
}

.box:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: #000;
}

    .wrapper {
        display: grid;
    grid-gap: 10px;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(1, minmax(100px,1fr) minmax(200px,2fr));
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
</div>
```

However, this only prints the last item:
[image]

I want to print out all items, what am I doing wrong? The keys should be in the black box and the values printed in the white box.

Comment: What does this have to do with JSON, though? Either the JSON.parse works, in which case this has nothing to do with JSON strings and your question is about a bog standard array of objects, or parsing fails, in which case literally everything after "why won't my JSON parse?" is irrelevant.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, I guess that makes sense. I thought I might be doing the parsing wrong and if there was a better way to handle keys and values. I'll remove the tag.

Comment: If the JSON.parse does not throw, then that's one aspect of your problem you don't need to worry about, removing (a small amount of) complexity from your problem. Now you just need to keep going: run through the [mcve] exercise to see what else isn't actually part of the problem =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes It always print the last one! because you are not appending element inside the loop, so that's why only last element get saved in `text` and `names` variable, Please modify your `JavaScript` code like below

```
const txt = '[{"prompts": "Breakfast","text": "The breakfast table is a microcosm of the wider world. How do we understand the people around us"},{"prompts": "Water Balloons","text": "This studio looks at the concept of water-balloons or rubber balloons"}]'


const obj = JSON.parse(txt);
for (let i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
  let text = obj[i].prompts;
  let names = obj[i].text;
  
  let prompt = document.createElement("div");
  prompt.setAttribute("class", "box");
  prompt.innerHTML = text;
  document.getElementsByClassName("wrapper")[0].appendChild(prompt);

  let output = document.createElement("div");
  output.setAttribute("class", "box");
  output.innerHTML = names;
  document.getElementsByClassName("wrapper")[0].appendChild(output);
}
```

**Output**
[image]